# Ошибка при установке PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Всем привет. ОС Windows, Python 3.6.2.

Пытаюсь установить PyQT v. 5.9 следующей командой в командной строке Windows
`pip install pyqt5`

Результат:

> ```
> C:\Users\Р>pip install pyqt5
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 3, in <module>
>     import pip
>   File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
>     import locale
>   File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\locale.py", line 16, in <module>
>     import re
>   File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 122, in <module>
>     import enum
>   File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\enum.py", line 2, in <module>
>     from types import MappingProxyType, DynamicClassAttribute
>   File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\types.py", line 171, in <module>
>     import functools as _functools
>   File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\functools.py", line 23, in <module>
>     from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
>   File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
>     from _weakref import (
> ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
> ```

Не пойму в чем проблема, помогите плиз.

Comment: А что показывает `pip -V`?

Comment: `pip -V`
возвращает то же самое

Comment: хм, pip что ли сломался? Просто -V должен был вернуть путь к `site-packages` в питоне, ну и версию его. Питон один в системе? `pip3 -V` работает? Смотрели в переменных путях PATH какие пути прописаны в питоничьи папки?

Comment: в системе питон 3.6.2 и 2.7 (С:\Python\Python36-32 С:\Python27). `pip3 -V`

Comment: `pip3 -V` - "pip3 не явл. внутр. или внеш. командой". Переменная среды пользователя PYTHONPATH содержит пути: D:\Ramil\GitHub\Tasks_Python\my_modules;
D:\Ramil\GitHub\Tasks_Python;
C:\Python\Python36-32\python36.zip;
C:\Python\Python36-32\DLLs;
C:\Python\Python36-32\lib;
C:\Python\Python36-32;
C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages;
C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg;
C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.

Comment: Системная переменная PYTHONPATH содержит тоже самое.  Команды ввожу через ком. строку - Windows + R, верно? В системе установлена Visual Studio + средства для разработки на питон, может из них возникает проблема?